# Reschedule a job that was unscheduled in Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).  Is it possible to reschedule a job that was unscheduled in Quartz?

I've a query.  Let's assume the following,

1. I've a job which I've scheduled.
2. Now, I've unscheduled the job.

Is it possible to reschedule the same job?

On same trigger or different trigger?

Comment: What happens if you just try scheduling the job the same way you scheduled it the first time?

Comment: I'm using JDBC Job store.If I unschedule a job, then everything from the DB will be removed. So, I'll not be able to get back that JOB. Else, I've to use my own persistence mechanism (like my own table). And, have to add the inputs to create the job before unscheduling the job. Then, have to add back the job back. My exact question is like, is there any mechanism provided by Quartz for this?

Comment: Maybe you need to "pauseJob" instead of unschedule. http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.                              pauseJob(JobKey jobKey)
      - Pause the JobDetail with the given key - by pausing all of its current Triggers.                                                            Won't this affect the triggers that are created commonly between jobs?

Comment: I think this will only pause the jobs for the given key. You may try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Will try and get back to you soon :-D